# How to configure AWS API Gateway so that User-Agent is available on X-Rray Analytics

Tags: aws-api-gateway, aws-xray

I want to include the AWS API Gateway step in my X-Ray trace results.

However when I enable X-Ray in my gateway on the production stage, the analytics tab in X-Ray only populates User-Agent as '-'

Example "Gateway Logging Config" - https://i.stack.imgur.com/RS88w.png

Example "Xray Analytics" - https://i.stack.imgur.com/x3VrJ.png

I can still see the user-agent available in the 2nd document of the X-Ray trace RAW data. Also when I disable X-Ray logging in Gateway the User-Agent begins being populated again.

Thanks in advance, for any input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for reaching out. We are aware about this issue and working with API Gateway team to add "user_agent" on the segment generated by the APIGW. I don't have any ETA but we have raised this issue with the APIGW team.

Concept :
When X-Ray is enabled for APIGW, APIGW generates Segment and sends to X-Ray service. This becomes root segment and since the user agent is missing on this root segment (known issue), X-Ray analytics tab shows "-" due to missing field in the root segment.

When you disable X-Ray for APIGW, the root segment is the application segment which you have enabled X-Ray instrumentation. This probably contains user-agent which is populated by X-Ray middleware. Since user-agent is present on the root segment in this case, the analytics tab shows the user-agent field being populated.

Thanks,
Yogi

Comment: Thanks for the information, please keep this thread updated if any ETA becomes available.